# How to remove all h2 and h3 tag in post content (all wordpress posts)(not just html view!)?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match

How to remove `h2` and `h3` tag in post content in all wordpress posts? *(not just html view)*

*(here in the stack there are several question just talking about how to hide this in the frontend)*

**NOTE:** Something more drastic, like removing actually removing from writing.

I've done this to get rid of unfortunate tags I've made in every wordpress blog post:

**WORKING:**

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin name: H2 end H3 tag Remover in the post_content 1.0
Plugin URI: https://myself.com
Description: This is a plugin to auto remove h2 end h3 tag in the post_content(LEIA O README.TXT)
Version: 1.0
Author: Ariane Gomes end Friends
Author URI: https://myself.com
*/
function remove_h2_end_h3_in_content($content) {
    $content_trash = array("<h2>", "</h2>", "<h3>", "</h3>");
    $content = str_replace($content_trash, '', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_h2_end_h3_in_content');
```

I did it above just on the fly, but it's about time I actually cleaned up this dirt instead of hiding it, because I'm unable to work with those tags until I remove that function from the system.

Something more drastic, like removing actually removing from writing.

anyone could write a code that **works AS a plugin** when just activating it?

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, '<h2>', '' );`

I need something that works in the plugin format, because via mysql console everyone knows how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't have any effect on your issue, but I think you can skip the $content_clean array and just use empty quotes in str_replace since you are using the same replacement for everything.

Comment: Woow oooh my God, it's a shame because it was a code to remove and exchange several errors of the French language and several other garbage and exchange for other things, so I made an adaptation to remove H2 in the greatest rush rsrs... thank you for the warning!

Comment: hey, do you mean that, remove h tags from content too now just replacing right? if the concept of just replacing the h tags then we can achieve it by javascript. or if you want to remove it then we can easily update our MySQL.

Comment: Thats good idea to create this type of plugin to remove specific tags. I can create it.

Comment: Or you can use the code in given answer for new post entry only.

Answer (score 2):

For new post entry it will replace the h2 and h3 tag before saving into the database :

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    // Change post title
    $content_trash = array("<h2>", "</h2>", "<h3>", "</h3>");
    $content = str_replace($content_trash, '', $data['post_content']);
    $data['post_content']= $content;
    return $data;
}
```

Just place this code into your functions.php, hope it will work for you.

Comment: What would be the name of your plugin? plugin killer SEO all future posts ?! condemn someone from ever being able to use H2, H3 .. why!?! this is to remove serious SEO errors in thousands of posts! the question makes this very easy to understand.

Comment: I think you have not read my answer properly, I have written clearly that the above code only works when you are entering new post. And if you want this type of coding you need all these functions which will work on insertion of post, otherwise your function will be called every time after insertion. Now coming to the plugin, I have mentioned that,it can be made and not made yet.  You have created plugin and that generate the issue, so be careful before you use any code. Here we can only provide solutions or help not any Plugin or Theme. Please read carefully the terms of stackoverflow.